# How to add a serial number to every row in MUI DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

First, some data is requested from the server.And then I want to add some data.There is no ID in the data value, but the form needs to display the serial number.

```
 const columns: GridColDef[] = [
        { 
            field: 'id' , 
            headerName: 'number', 
            filterable: false,
            renderCell:(index:any) => `${index + 1}`
        },
        { field: 'code' , headerName: ' code' },
        { field: 'type' , headerName: ' type' },
  ]
```

```
<DataGrid rows={row} columns={columns} />
```

But index is Nan.How do I generate a serial number in each line in a table when I add a new data?

Answer (score 3):

We can achieve this by using `getRowIndex` method.
`getRowIndex` method takes the filed name as a parameter and returns the index of the row to which this filed belongs. so the trick is to pass a unique field to this method.

The solution to your problem would look something like this:

*Column field :*

```
   {
        field: 'id' , 
        headerName: 'number', 
        filterable: false,
        renderCell:(index) => index.api.getRowIndex(index.row.code)
    }
```

*Data Grid :*

```
<DataGrid rows={row} columns={columns} getRowId= {(row) => row.code}/>
```

In the above example I am asuming that code is a unique field. If its hard to have a unique field, you can generate one field with combinations of code, type and so on.

In this case your solution would look something like this:

*Column field :*

```
   {
        field: 'id' , 
        headerName: 'number', 
        filterable: false,
        renderCell:(index) => index.api.getRowIndex(index.row.code + '_' + index.row.type)
    }
```

*Data Grid :*

```
<DataGrid rows={row} columns={columns} getRowId= {(row) => row.code + '_' + row.type}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume some previous answers were valid before they changed the API.

Personally, I just recently started using the MUI DataGrid component.

My solution is very similar to the previous answers.
`getRowIndex` does not exist in `6.0.2`.
The only API method I could find is `getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows`, and it seems to do the trick (though that "relative to visible rows" does concern me a bit):

```
// ...

      {
        sortable: true,
        field: 'lineNo',
        headerName: '#',
        flex: 0,
        editable: false,
        renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams<DatasetEntryEntity>) =>
          params.api.getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows(params.row.id) + 1,
      },
// ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

since mui released version 6, the `getRowIndex` API has been deprecated. instead you can use:

```
{
    field: "id",
    headerName: "number",
    filterable: false,
    renderCell: (index) =>
      index.api.getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows(index.row.code) + 1,
  }
```

`getRowIndexRelativeToVisibleRows` get the index of a row relative to the rows that are reachable by scroll.

ref: [GridApi Interface](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-api/#properties)

Answer (score 2):

The last answer gives the right result, but sometimes it gives NaN
so I'm using this type

```
renderCell: (params) => params.api.getAllRowIds().indexOf(params.id)+1
```

This works fine and also tells me whether it's right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the row index by calling the `getRowIndex` from the api:

```
renderCell: (index) => index.api.getRowIndex(index.row.id) + 1,
```

So using your example:

```
 const columns: GridColDef[] = [
        { 
            field: 'id' , 
            headerName: 'number', 
            filterable: false,
            renderCell: (index) => index.api.getRowIndex(index.row.id) + 1,
        },
        { field: 'code' , headerName: ' code' },
        { field: 'type' , headerName: ' type' },
  ]
```

If a column has `sortable: true`, this index number won't change regardless of how the column is sorted - it will always be 1 for the first line item, 2 for the second, etc.

Likewise, for grids with pagination enabled, the index will match based on the page (ie: if there are 5 line items per page, regardless of sorting, the first line item will always be 1 on page 1, 6 on page 2, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
renderCell: (params) => params.api.getAllRowIds().indexOf(params.id)+1
```

Comment: This is an exact repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/a/77492553/7264739